# Count and Percentage of an aggregated field in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

i am new to tableau, i have created a calculated field (as below) based on which I want the find the percentage.

```
If [x] = > 10 Then "A" 
elseif [x] < 10 Then "B" 
elseif [x] < 5 Then "C" 
END
```

I now need to know the percentage of A, B, & C , is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check out this link so that we can better assist you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1. The calculation (call it 'Letter') needs to be as follows to avoid the current ambiguity between B and C (also use <= not =>)

   IF [X] < 5 Then "C"
   ELSEIF  [X] < 10 Then "B"
   ELSEIF  [X] >= 10 Then "A"
   END
2. Add letter to the rows shelf
3. Add x to the text mark and change it from sum to count by right clicking the pill
4. In the analysis menu, select Percentage of then Column

Comment: thanks much @reusen. i also wanted to calculate the percentage of A, B, and C as well, meaning based on the above caluculation, could i add another field which shows me the count of A, B and C?